# Hashtable Keys and producing the same values

Tags: c#, hashtable

I'm trying to understand how a hashtable works. In this example, I can clearly see this hashtable contains keys that contain the exact same value. Obviously this works, but I'm trying to understand why? Is it correct to say the hash function simply points to a different memory location, all coincidentally containing the same binary? I can't seem to find a proper answer in a search..

```
        Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
        h.Add(1, "lol");
        h.Add(2, "lol");
        h.Add(3, "lol");
```

Comment: A hash table or dictionary is a data structure that links a specific key to a value. The key is important, the value is not, the value is simply stored for the key. It works because this is the point of the dictionary. Why do you think it shouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Add` method accepts the key and then the value.  Try switching the parameters and see what happens.  You'll get an `ArgumentException` because only unique keys are allowed,

Also see the doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.add(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes but what if I have want to have two keypairs that both have the same value? Perhaps my 'keys' Sam and Alex both happen to have the same passwords, '123abc'. so my two keypairs would be <Sam,123abc> and <Alex,123abc>. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: That is perfectly acceptable, as your example proves.  Keys are 1, 2, and 3 with the same value "lol".